# An 'invite to which' or an 'invitation to which' or 'whose invite'?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, vocabulary, passive-voice

> All prompts and learning resources will be released on our Discord server, and an invite to it shall be e-mailed to the participants on registration.

I am adding the previous sentence to an official document and am quite confused as to how this sentence shall be structured as something about it does not sound good right now.

I google'd the use of 'whose' for inanimatable objects and got weird answers so could not decide if I could say *...on Discord, whose invite shall be sent...* 
and, I also could not decide if it would make sense to say *an invite to which shall be sent* **or** an *invitation to which shall be sent*.

There are three aspects of this question and I still am quite confused, what is the best way to convey the message?

Comment: The use of "invite" as a noun meaning "invitation" is common but informal.

Comment: _Will be sent_, not _shall_.

Comment: On something that can be described as an "official document" you want to use the word _invitation_, not _invite_; it doesn't falute high enough. Also, unless you're **trying** to confuse people, don't use _shall_ instead of _will_, and definitely don't use both of them in the same sentence; it makes people wonder what the difference is. And you don't want to use _whose invitation_; that's not how possessive relatives work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary (OED) labels the noun form of *invite* as colloquial (used in or characteristic of conversation, especially familiar and informal conversation) . So, I think *an invitation to it* would be more appropriate